# Should I spawn a new node process per game room?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, scalability

I am making a card game on node.js and I am thinking about spawning a new process per game room. I plan on doing the connection using fork(). After quite some research, I found that this isn't the best approach, because I should have a node process per physical core. But isn't my approach better for scalability and modularity? If let's say a game room crashes, it wouldn't crash the rest of them. Can someone help me analyse a bit better the situation? I plan on running the game on aws EC2 instances and expect a maximum of 1500 concurrent users, playing on rooms of 4 people, and communicating with socket.io messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single Node instance can handle that type of load, as one of NodeJS's strongpoints is real time communication and *many* concurrent connections.

Regarding crashes, you need to plan for those. Some initial tips:

- Catch errors and log error messages so that your Node instance does not completely fail. Often errors may stop that particular function chain from finishing correctly, but will not kill your process.
- Persist your game state to another service, like a database, so things (like connections) can recover. Use Case example: "User loses connection and logs back in, they are re-connected to the room and can see the game in its current state"
- You can auto-recover your Node process by running something like forever or PM2 (there are others). These will monitor and restart on process failure (though that shouldn't happen too often).

Comment: Currently I am saving some data (like a player's cards or the currently played cards) on an object. From your response I assume that this is a bad practice. As my database, I am using mongodb with mongoose. Wouldn't it be inefficient for me to query the database over and over (2 times per player turn - to update their hand and the currently played combination, with around 100 total turns, at around 250 games)?

Comment: "inefficient" is difficult to diagnose. Do you mean "tax your machine resources" or "will players notice"? I think NodeJS (and Mongo) are fine choices for your game and you should build a prototype now, and optimize any bottlenecks later. Storing state in an object is fine, but you run the risk that if the process dies or goes out of scope, you lose your state entirely. Like optimization, I'd suggest building you game logic first (in objects), and then persisting later when you try to make your game more resilient to disconnects/crashes/etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will definitely consider saving state in a database.